# How to consume all valid data in one kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

In our project, we expect all the data exist in the specific topic can be consumed by Kafka engine, but we tried two ways, however, none of them works.

1. Tried to put key-word [auto_offset_reset] when create kafka engine table just like below. No error return when created table, but only incremental data in the topic is consumed in this way.

```sql
CREATE TABLE xx.yyy (
`shop_id` String,
 `last_updated_at` String
) ENGINE = Kafka('XXX', 'shop_price_center.t_sku_shop_price', 'xxx', 'JSONEachRow', '', '', 1, 0, 0, 20000, 
auto_offset_reset='earliest')
```

2. Change the configuration in xml file, still not works

```xml
<kafka>
  <debug>cgrp</debug>
  <auto_offset_reset>earliest</auto_offset_reset>
</kafka>
```

Any guru can show me a complete example to show the solution? Very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Data can be read from Kafka just once (after each read the consumer's offset is moved forward, therefore, repeated reading the same data is not possible) so need to use materialized view that listens to Kafka topic and put data to ordinary-table:

```sql
/* ordinary table */
CREATE TABLE xx.yyy (
  shop_id String,
  last_updated_at String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY tuple() /* just demo settings */
ORDER BY (last_updated_at, shop_id); /* just demo settings */

/* Kafka 'queue' */
CREATE TABLE xx.yyy_queue (
  shop_id String,
  last_updated_at String
)
ENGINE = Kafka SETTINGS
  kafka_broker_list = '..',
  kafka_topic_list = 'topic',
  kafka_group_name = '..',
  kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow',
  kafka_row_delimiter = '\n',
  kafka_skip_broken_messages = 1,
  kafka_num_consumers = 1,
  kafka_max_block_size = 1000;

/* materialized view: it transfers data from topic to sql-table */
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW xx.yyy_consumer TO xx.yyy AS 
SELECT
 shop_id,
 last_updated_at 
FROM xx.yyy_queue;
```

The Kafka-specific settings such as *auto_offset_reset* should be defined in xml-file located in */etc/clickhouse-server/config.d*-directory not in table definition:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
    <kafka>
        <auto_offset_reset>earliest</auto_offset_reset>
    </kafka>
</yandex>
```

Select data only from *xx.yyy*-ordinary table not *xx.yyy_queue*:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM xx.yyy;
```

Comment: very appreciate your reply, but i am using the exactly same way as you did above. And for you suggest that modify the setting in /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d-directory we will have a try